# iOS, weird text alignment loss after segue

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uikit, alignment, uilabel

I have a view, which looks like this:

[image]

As you see the "Status" label containing the word "Lukket" is aligned centrally.
When i perform a segue, pop a new view on and pop it off, the view looks like this:

[image]

As you see, the text is now aligned left.

I am setting the alignment in the storyboard, "Lukket" is a UILabel.

Comment: Are you sure it is the text alignment that are changing instead of your layout ?

Answer (score 0):

Check if Accessory is set to "None" in your cell. That could cause the wrong alignment.